# How can I output the response from one VBS file to a text file or a UIPath variable?

Tags: vbscript, io-redirection, uipath

I have written some simple VBScript code to use a GET REST HTTP request. It is as follows:

```
endpoint="somethingsomething" 
parameter ="?someparameters&sysparm_limit=10000"  
Set objXmlHttpMain = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")  
URL = endpoint & resource & parameter 

On Error Resume Next   
objXmlHttpMain.open "GET",URL, False, "admin", "jhdsjkF"  
objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "UserID", "admin"
objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Password", "jhdsjkF"
objXmlHttpMain.send

response = objXmlHttpMain.responsetext
```

Ideally, I want to store this response in a UIPath string variable to use it further in the sequence. Is there a way to do that?

However, if there isn't could you assist me in putting this response in a text file? I want the text file to be the same no matter how many times the VBScript is executed, and for the response to be written after the file gets cleared.

Comment: VB.NET is not VBScript.  Dont use irrelevant tags.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` or `ADODB.Stream` to save response to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why ...

```
uipath = response
```

or

```
uipath = objXmlHttpMain.responsetext
```